# JavaScript script not working

Tags: javascript

I need to write a javascript to make certain calculations by taking data from a form. I have written the script and ensured all the ids and variables are correct. For some reason, my script doesn't seem to run. Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong??

This is my form action.

```
<body>
        <div class="header">
          Financial Calculator
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="calc.js"></script>
        <div class="calc">
        <form name="calc" method="post" onsubmit="calc()">
        <table align="center">
               <tr>
                   <th></th>
                       <th>Lease Data</th>
                   <th>Purchase Data</th>
                   <th>Purchase Data with Rebate</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Cost</td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="cost1" placeholder="Please enter in $"></td>
               <td><input type="text" name="cost2" placeholder="Please enter in $"></td>
               <td><input type="text" name="cost3" placeholder="Please enter in $"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Downpayment</td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="downpayment1" placeholder="Please enter in $"></td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="downpayment2" placeholder="Please enter in $"></td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="downpayment3" placeholder="Please enter in $"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Period</td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="period1" placeholder="Please enter in months"></td>
               <td><input type="text" name="period2" placeholder="Please enter in years"></td>
               <td><input type="text" name="period3" placeholder="Please enter in years"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Rebates/Incentives</td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="rebate" placeholder="Please enter in $"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Interest</td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="interest1" placeholder="Please enter in %"></td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="interest2" placeholder="Please enter in %"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Monthly Payment</td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="monthly_payment1" placeholder="Please enter in $"></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Distance Limit</td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="distance_limit" placeholder="Please enter in miles"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Extra Miles</td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="extra_miles" placeholder="Please enter in miles"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Cost for extra mile</td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="cost_extra" placeholder="Please enter in $"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td><br><input type="submit" value="Calculate"></td>
               </tr>

        </table>
        <table id="result">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Purchase with finance</th>
            <th>Purchase with Rebate</th>
            <th>Lease</th>
            <th>Purchase after Lease</th>
            <th>Purchase after lease with additional miles</th>
        </tr>
<tr>
    <td>Total Monthly Payments</td>
    <td id="mp1"><input type="text"></td>
    <td id="mp2"><input type="text"></td>
    <td id="mp3"><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Ownership Cost</td>
    <td id="oc1"><input type="text"></td>
    <td id="oc2"><input type="text"></td>
    <td id="oc3"><input type="text"></td>
    <td id="oc4"><input type="text"></td>
    <td id="oc5"><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Per month owned</td>
    <td id="pmo1"><input type="text"></td>
    <td id="pmo2"><input type="text"></td>
    <td id="pmo3"><input type="text"></td>
    <td id="pmo4"><input type="text"></td>
    <td id="pmo5"><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Residual Value</td>
    <td id="res1"><input type="text"></td>
    <td id="res2"><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr> <td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr> <td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr> <td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
          </table>
        </form>
        </div>
  </body>
```

My Javascript is:

```
function calc() 
{
    var cost1 = (parseFloat)(document.calc.cost1.value);
    var downpayment1  = (parseFloat)(document.calc.downpayment1.value);
    var mp1 = (parseFloat)(document.calc.monthly_payment1.value);
    var period1 = (parseFloat)(document.calc.period1.value);
    var extra_miles = (parseFloat)(document.calc.extra_miles.value);
    var cost_extra_miles = (parseFloat)(document.calc.cost_extra_miles.value);

    var extra_cost = extra_miles * cost_extra_miles;
    var res_amt = 0.56 * cost1;
    var totmp = mp1 * period1; 
    var ocost1 = downpayment1 + totmp + extra_cost;
    var omonth1 = ocost1 / period1;

    var ocost2 = ocost1 + res_amt;
    var omonth2 = ocost2 / period1;

    var ocost3 = ocost2 - extra_cost;
    var omonth3 = ocost3 / period1;


    var cost2 = (parseFloat)(document.calc.cost2.value);
    var downpayment2  = (parseFloat)(document.calc.downpayment2.value);
    var period2 = (parseFloat)(document.calc.period2.value);
    var interest1 = (parseFloat)(document.calc.interest1.value);

    var finance1 = cost2 - downpayment2;
    var mp2 = ((interest1 / 12) * period2) - finance1;
    var omonth_woreb = mp2 * period2;
    var ocost_woreb = omonth_woreb + downpayment2;
    var pmonth_woreb = ocost_woreb / period2;
    var resvalue1 = ocost_woreb - res_amt;


    var cost3 = (parseFloat)(document.calc.cost3.value);
    var downpayment3  = (parseFloat)(document.calc.downpayment3.value);
    var period3 = (parseFloat)(document.calc.period3.value);
    var interest2 = (parseFloat)(document.calc.interest2.value);    
    var rebate = (parseFloat)(document.calc.rebate.value);

    var finance2 = cost3 - downpayment3 -rebate;
    var mp3 = ((interest1 / 12) * period3) - finance2;
    var omonth_wreb = mp3 * period3;
    var ocost_wreb = omonth_wreb + downpayment3;
    var pmonth_wreb = ocost_wreb / period3;
    var resvalue2 = ocost_wreb - res_amt;



document.getElementById("mp1").innerHTML = ; 
document.getElementById("mp2").innerHTML = ;
document.getElementById("mp3").innerHTML = totmp;


document.getElementById("oc1").innerHTML = ocost_woreb; 
document.getElementById("oc2").innerHTML = ocost_wreb;
document.getElementById("oc3").innerHTML = ocost1;
document.getElementById("oc4").innerHTML = ocost2;
document.getElementById("oc5").innerHTML = ocost3;


document.getElementById("pmo1").innerHTML = pmonth_woreb; 
document.getElementById("pmo2").innerHTML = pmonth_wreb;
document.getElementById("pmo3").innerHTML = omonth1;
document.getElementById("pmo4").innerHTML = omonth2;
document.getElementById("pmo5").innerHTML = omonth3;

document.getElementById("res1").innerHTML = resvalue1; 
document.getElementById("res2").innerHTML = resvalue2;

}
```

Comment: Show more of your HTML.  Do you have any button, or anything that will trigger the submit?  Also, have you put anything inside the `calc` function like an `alert` or `console.log` to see if you're getting into it?

Comment: The whole form is missing. So hard to tell if you have any issues in there. But a good starting point, would to be to use chrome to debug this. Open the developer tools and click on console. Its a god send for debugging javascript.

Comment: The form is fine. I have a calculate button. Anyway I've updated the question with the whole html code for my form. Please have a look.

Comment: And I've made all the suggested edits of removing parantheses around parsefloat and entering ' ' for empty string.

Answer (score 1):

```
var cost1 = (parseFloat)(document.calc.cost1.value);
```

You do not wrap parseFloat in parens.

```
var cost1 = parseFloat(document.calc.cost1.value);
```

And you are not cancelling the form submission, the page is refereshing. Easy way to cancel the submission is returning false

```
onsubmit="calc();return false;"
```

and this is an error

```
document.getElementById("mp1").innerHTML = ; 
document.getElementById("mp2").innerHTML = ;
```

Look at this:

The id is on the td, not the input. You are not going to get a value in there if that was your plan.

Comment: mp1 in the document.getElementByID is the id of a text box in the form where I want the result to be displayed.

Comment: And I stated textboxes do not have innerHTML. It is value

Comment: I didn't quite understand. Can you tell me how to write the code? I mean a small example where I'm writing into a textbox. I don't know what value you're talking about!

Comment: Replace `innerHTML` with `value`!

Comment: I tried that. Still no result. Sorry I'm just starting to learn javascript. I've applied all the changes suggested by everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The following lines aren't syntactically valid:

```
document.getElementById("mp1").innerHTML = ; 
document.getElementById("mp2").innerHTML = ;
```

If you want to empty the contents of an input, you could use `value` and an empty string:

```
document.getElementById("mp1").value = '';
document.getElementById("mp2").value = '';
```